# Change Graph Series Fillcolor in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

AS shown in image, i want to change Fill color by point (referring project state in my case so),
[visual for my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGhPQ.png)

code i have used so far to achieve this is below,

```
    $(function () {
    $('#ao-projectssummry-chart').highcharts({
        type: "spline",
        title: null,
        borderRadius : null,
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['May2016', 'June2016', 'July2016', 'August2016', 'september2016', 'November2016'],
            opposite: true
            //type: 'datetime',
            //min: Date.UTC(2011, 4, 31),
            //max: Date.UTC(2012, 11, 6)
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            title : null
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 20,
                borderRadius: null,
                radius: 0
            },
            marker: {
                radius : 0
            }

        },
        credits : {
            enabled : false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled : false
        },

        series: [{
            name: "Project 1",
            data: [1, 1, {
                y: 1,
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)',
                                overlapping: true
                            }
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                            }
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                    }
                }
                ]
        },
        {
            name: "Project 2",

            data: [2, {
                y: 2,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)',
                    overlapping : true
                }
            }, 2, 2, 2, {
                y:2,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)',
                    overlapping: true
                }
            },
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

so, how can i change the plotoption color by point? also how can i achieve background lines shown in the picture?

Any help would be appreciated! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the question is different than what I read it as the first time. Rather than changing the color of the point markers, you want to change the color of the segments between markers.

Here is an approach that achieves what you are asking for, using the `columnrange` series type instead of a line. This allows more flexibility and control.

**The idea:**

First, set the type, and invert the chart (columnrange is a vertical series type; to make it horizontal, invert the chart - the x axis is now the vertical axis, and the y axis is now the horizontal axis):

```
chart: {
  type: "columnrange",
  inverted: true
}
```

Update the axis settings accordingly (swap x for y).

Set your data with an `x` value, a `low` value (starting point), and a `high` value (end point).

Set the color to whatever you want:

```
data: [{
  x: 1,
  low: Date.UTC(2016,3,15),
  high: Date.UTC(2016,4,21),
  color: 'rgb(0,156,255)'
},{
   x: 3,
   low: Date.UTC(2016,2,7),
   high: Date.UTC(2016,6,15),
   color: "rgb(204,0,0)"
 }]
```

To place the markers, add a separate series, either line or scatter (I use line, with a `lineWidth: 0`, because scatter series use a different tooltip model, and are not as easy to integrate with other series, if the tooltip is important to you. But otherwise, both work the same).

**Marker series:**

```
{
  name: 'Markers',
  type: 'line',
  data: [
  {
    x: 1,
    y: Date.UTC(2016,2,15),
    marker: { 
      fillColor:"#9CCB00"
    }
  }
```

**Example:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/x7c3t81n/

**Output:**

[image: gantt]

Comment: @jilbriggs this is brilliant!! thanks a lot :) :) :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that in the `data` array directly:

**Example code**:

```
data: [5,4,3,2,5,6,7,9, {y:6, marker: { enabled: true, radius: 10, fillColor: 'red'}},3,2,5,6,7]
```

Anything that you can specify in the plotOptions that affects the data point, you can specify in this way for a specific data point.

Any point for which you don't specify anything, follows the default options, or the options specified in the plotOptions.

**Fiddle**:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/126/

**Output**:

[image: color points]

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for your reply. In my case the pointers are images/Icons, i have to change the Plot Line colors (i mean, for example that blue line in your demo) is there any option to change it?

Comment: Use [`marker.symbol`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.symbol) option.

Comment: @pawelFus using marker.symbol we can get icons on the points, but i want to change the fill color of the series line

Comment: If you want to change the plot line color, just use your own theme and apply to the chart. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes

Comment: Right, sorry! It's kind of Monday today ;) In that case use [`series.color`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.color).

Comment: i think Monday still continues :D ;) , http://i.stack.imgur.com/xGhPQ.png if you check this image, in one series you could see multiple color, example(blue.green,purple), so how can we achieve that?

Comment: @krishnakinnera krisha, i understand we can change series color by setting color array, but in single series how do we get multiple colors?

Comment: i have created working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/sh46010L/5/) here, please check the first series color, but that doesnt working.

Comment: @IamSarav in that case, you will need to either 1) use multiple series, or 2) use the **columnrange** series type instead of a line (set *inverted: true* on the chart options object), and change the fillColor of each point in the same manner that I have in the answer above

Comment: @jilbriggs checked it, thats brilliant!!